# Can anyone explain we about this warning?

Tags: tabula

I am using Tabula to read some tables from pdf files.
While reading I am getting below warning, and might be because of that some of the pages are not getting read.
Please help if anyone got the same warning/error.

**WARNING: Format 14 cmap table is not supported and will be ignored.**